# Why does my on_message event doesn't work (discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot that worked fine but I wanted to start using cogs because I thought it was a nicer way to write my code but now my on_message doesn't work any more and it doesn't show any error messages I searched how to fix it in the whole internet and all explanations didn't work for me so I decided to ask here. So here is my code:

```
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'my token'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")


class Interactions(commands.Cog):
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        msg = message.content
        hi = ["hi", "hello", "hi!", "hello!"]
        bye = ["bye", "good bye", "bye!", "good bye!"]

        # Messages in english
        if str(msg).lower() in hi:
            await message.channel.send('Hello!')

        if str(msg).lower == 'how are you?':
            await message.channel.send("I'm fine")

        if str(msg).lower == "what's your favorite food?":
            await message.channel.send("Sushi with sweet potato!")

        if str(msg).lower == "what do you eat?":
            await message.channel.send(
                "I don't eat, I'm just a simple bot :pensive:")

        if str(msg).lower == "are you fine?":
            await message.channel.send("Yes, I am")

        if str(msg).lower in bye:
            await message.channel.send("Good bye!")

def run():
    bot.add_cog(Interactions(bot)
    bot.run(TOKEN)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Import:**

```
from discord.ext.commands import command, Cog
```

**Rest of the code:**

```
TOKEN = 'my token'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")


class Interactions(commands.Cog):
    @commands.Cog.listener()
  
    async def on_message(self, message):
        pass
```

This should work, if not just ping me ;)